# "Differential" of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$. What is the definition of the operator $d$ in the expression: $d\mu$. For example, I have an exercise where at one point:

\begin{equation}
d\mu(x) = \frac{d x}{1+x^2}
\end{equation}

I would said this a "differential" of $\mu$, but I can not find any definition of this kind on the Internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a notation related to [Radon-Nykodym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) theorem. In this context, this means that for each non-negative measurable function,
$$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}dx.$$

Comment: Or, written another way, $\frac{d\mu}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: IMO this does not quite answer the question.  Expressions like $dx$, $df$ are just differentials (particular cases of differential forms).  What it $d\mu$?

Comment: My intuition suggests me that $d\mu$ must be something like "density" of $\mu$, but i think that in mathematics *measure density* is a relative notion: only density of one measure with respect to another can be defined.

Comment: Moreover, one should ask not only for the meaning of $d\mu(x)$, but for the meaning of $f(x)d\mu(x)$.  I would hope for a concise and precise answer, like in the case of $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ (here $f(x)dx$ is a differential form, to be integrated over the oriented interval $[a,b]$).

Comment: Just a thought: can the formalism of [generalised functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) be somehow used to unify $dx$ and $d\mu$?

Comment: @Alexey $\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)\,dx$ probably means integration of $g$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure (or a different implicitly given measure) here. The measure $\mu$ is then defined by its density with respect to Lebesgue. Nothing in the question nor the answer are meant to be differential forms.

Comment: @epimorphic, $g(x)dx$ is a differential form.  To integrate it over $\mathbb{R}$, no measure is needed, only the differential structure (tangent spaces at each point of $\mathbb{R}$, etc.) and the orientation.

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)d\mu =\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)|dx|$ (no orientation on $\mathbb{R}$ is needed for the second integral).  The question remains: what is $g(x)d\mu(x)$?

Comment: I agree however that the expression $f(x)dx$ can be generalized outside of the context of differential forms.  For example, if $f$ is continuous and $g$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dg(x)$ is defined (no measure needed either).

Comment: @Alexey $d\mu$ is not a differential form. If you look e.g. at the point process literature, you see similar "differential" notation for quantities which clearly have nothing to do with differential forms, and which have a vague connection to measures.

Comment: @Chill2Macht, IMO, there is still no clear answer to the question: "What is the definition of the operator $d$ in the expression $dμ$?"

Comment: @Alexey There is a clear answer: it has no stand-alone meaning, it is just crappy notation inherited via tradition. It doesn't represent a differential form.